# Oracle REGEX to Match all Records that end with a Specific String

Tags: regex, oracle

I am working in Oracle and have a value like so:

```
A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4
```

I want to be able to remove any values that don't end in either '.pas' or '.poc' as well as any spaces preceding those values to obtain the following:

```
A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4
```

I have attempted several solutions, but the most recent attempt was:

`($|\s)(.*?)\.poc|(.*?)\.pas`

However, that only matches the very first instance.

How do I go about matching all instances?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That looks like you want to remove any values that *do* end in either '.pas' or '.poc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to remove any values that don't end in either `.pas` or `.poc` as well as any spaces preceding those values

Oracle does not support look-ahead/behind in regular expressions (otherwise you could use something like `(?:^|\s)\S+(?<!\.p(?:as|oc))(?=\s|$)`) so one way is to double-up the space delimiters between terms and prepend and append space to the string so that every term starts and ends with a space and then you can match:

- `\s\S*\.p(oc|as)\s` - the leading space followed by a non-space sub-string terminating in either `.pas` or `.poc` and then a trailing space; or
- `\s\S+\s` the leading space followed by any other non-space sub-string terminating in a space.

That should match all the terms and then use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to replace each term with only matches to the first of those patterns. Finally, remove the extra delimiters:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TRIM(
         REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ' ' || REPLACE(value, ' ', '  ') || ' ',
             '(\s\S*\.p(oc|as)\s)|\s\S+\s',
             '\1'
           ),
           '  ',
           ' '
         )
       ) AS updated_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4 | A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc |

---

However, based on your expected output, it looks like the question should be:

> I want to be able to remove any values that **do** end in either `.pas` or `.poc` as well as any spaces preceding those values

Then you can duplicate the delimiters, remove the terms matching `\s\S*\.p(oc|as)\s` and then remove the duplicated delimiters:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TRIM(
         REPLACE(
           REGEXP_REPLACE(
             ' ' || REPLACE(value, ' ', '  ') || ' ',
             '\s\S*\.p(oc|as)\s'
           ),
           '  ',
           ' '
         )
       ) AS updated_value
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| VALUE | UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4 | A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4pAdWVqr)

Answer (score 1):

Split the input string using `regexp_substr` and `connect by`, filter out any substrings ending in `.pas` or `.poc`, and then concatenate the remaining substrings using `listagg`.

```
select
  listagg(upd_val, chr(13)) within group (order by rn) upd_val,
  value
from (
  select
    level rn,
    value,
    regexp_substr(value, '\S+', 1, level) upd_val
  from T
  connect by regexp_substr(value, '\S+', 1, level) is not null
)
where not regexp_like(upd_val, '\.p(as|oc)$')
group by value;
```

Results:

```
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|       UPD_VAL        |                                                       VALUE                                                       |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total | A.H.4.1.2.0000.pas A.H.4.1.2.0000.poc A.H.410000.poc A.H.420000.poc A.H.4.1.2.0000.Total A.H.4 B.I.5.2.3.1111.poc |
| A.H.4                |                                                                                                                   |
+----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Try it on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WClfEugI).